# How to filter a list based on the content of another list of a different type?

Tags: java

I have two lists:

1. `List<SomeObject> objectList;`
2. `List<String> stringList;`

While `SomeObject` has a member `name` which is of type `String`.
What is the best way to check if `stringList` contains a string that is *not* a name of any `someObject` in `objectList`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate through the objects in objectList and add each name to a `Set<String>` (let's call it `nameSet`). Then call `nameSet.containsAll(stringList)`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd propose to build a `Set<String>` with the names of all objects in the first list and then check the second list against that set.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
for (SomeObject o : objectList) {
    set.add(o.getName());
}

for (String s : stringList) {
    if (!set.contains(s)) {
        ... // do whatever
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sets:

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
for(SomeObject ob : objectList)
    set.add(ob.name);

 boolean ok = false;
 for(String name : stringList)
     if(!set.contains(name)){
         ok = true;
         break
 }
```

//ok is true if your condition is satisfied

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static boolean containsSameName()
{
    for(String s : stringList)
    {
        for(SomeObject obj : objectList)
        {
            if(obj.getName().equals(s)) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```