# Stream Filter List based on Combination of values from another List

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

**Need:** To filter out data in list - 1 based on the values present in list - 2 with multiple criteria i.e. combination of Date & Order Number

**Issue:** Able to filter based on 1 criteria. But when I try adding another filter condition it treats it as 2 separate & not as combination. Unable to figure out how to make it as a combination.

Hope issue faced is clear.

**Research:** I referred to my earlier query on similar need - [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246998/stream-filter-of-1-list-based-on-another-list) . Also checked - [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054773/java-8-streams-multiple-filters-vs-complex-condition)

List 1: (All Orders)

- [Date | OrderNumber | Time | Company | Rate ]
- [2014-10-01 | 12345 | 10:00:01 | CompA | 1000]
- [2015-03-01 | 23456 | 08:00:01 | CompA | 2200]
- [2016-08-01 | 34567 | 09:00:01 | CompA | 3300]
- [2017-09-01 | 12345 | 11:00:01 | CompA | 4400]
- [2017-09-01 | 98765 | 12:00:01 | CompA | 7400]

List 2: (Completed Orders)

- [Date | OrderNumber | Time]
- [2014-10-01 | 12345 | 10:00:01]
- [2015-03-01 | 23456 | 08:00:01]
- [2016-08-01 | 34567 | 09:00:01]
- [2017-09-01 | 98765 | 12:00:01]

Expected O/p after filter :

- [Date | OrderNumber | Time | Company | Rate]
- [2017-09-01 | 12345 | 11:00:01 | CompA | 4400]

**Code:**

```
// Data extracted from MySQL database
// List 1: All Orders
List<ModelAllOrders> listOrders = getDataFromDatabase.getTable1();
// List 2: Completed Orders
List<ModelCompletedOrders> listCompletedOrders = getDataFromDatabase.getTable2();

// Filter with 1 criteria works
Set<Integer> setOrderNumbers = listCompletedOrders.stream().map(ModelCompletedOrders::getOrderNumber).collect(Collectors.toSet());

listOrders = listOrders.stream().filter(p -> !setOrderNumbers.contains(p.getOrderNumber()).collect(Collectors.toList());

// Below not working as expected when trying to combinational filter
Set<LocalDate> setDates = listCompletedOrders.stream().map(ModelCompletedOrders::getDate).collect(Collectors.toSet());

listOrders = listOrders.stream().filter(p -> !setDates.contains(p.getDate()) && !setOrderNumbers.contains(p.getOrderNumber()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hint: use your database to do filtering and selection - that's literally what it's built for. It will do it more simply and far faster than any code you write could ever do.

Comment: @BoristheSpider thanks for that. Yes am aware, but was exploring if this was possible using Streams.

Comment: What exactly do you want to filter on? You're creating a set of order numbers that you're using inside a logical expression (i.e. insisting on these being unique), but you have 2 orders with the same order number `12345`.

Comment: @John The combination of Date & Order Number is unique. I need to check if that unique combination is present in List-2, if yes then filter out, if not then output should contain that row. Hope am clear.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked for logic that will do this:

> The combination of Date & Order Number is unique. I need to check if that unique combination is present in List-2, if yes then filter out, if not then output should contain that row.

[Stream::filter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) will return a subset of the stream where the filter predicate returns true (i.e. it filters out those objects in the stream where the predicate is false).

```
listOrders = listOrders.stream().filter(p -> !setDates.contains(p.getDate()) && !setOrderNumbers.contains(p.getOrderNumber()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Your code expression here says "show me orders where the order's date does not appear in the list of prior orders AND where the order's order number does not appear in the list of prior orders".  Your logical expression is wrong (you're getting confused between what in electronics would be called [positive vs negative logic](http://sce2.umkc.edu/csee/hieberm/281_new/lectures/basic-electrical-components/pos-neg-logic.html)).

You want either:

```
listOrders = listOrders.stream().filter(p -> !(setDates.contains(p.getDate()) && setOrderNumbers.contains(p.getOrderNumber())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> "show me orders where both the order's date and order's id are not
>   present in the list of prior orders"

or:

```
listOrders = listOrders.stream().filter(p -> !setDates.contains(p.getDate()) || !setOrderNumbers.contains(p.getOrderNumber()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> "show me orders where either the order's date has not been seen before
>   OR the order's id has not been seen before"

Comment: Thanks, am aware of the +ve / -ve logic. I am using the negation in filter to remove orders already completed. 
In this case, I know the problem is caused because am setting up 2 separate sets (i.e. Order No. & Date). So even if I use 
!(setDates.contains(p.getDate()) && setOrderNumbers.contains(p.getOrderNumber())))
it will not give the expected output, as it treats it as separate criteria not combination.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it treats it as separate criteria not combination".  Please would you post the contents of the 2 sets, plus what the output of your code is?