# How to convert for each loops into Java streams and lambda function?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a use-case in Java where I need to populate one of the lists (say x) based on the id of the other list(say y) and to fetch the result from that list.

```java
List<LightRecruiterScholarResponse> responses = eventScholarRepository.findScholarDetailsByEventId(eventId);
List<InterviewDto> interviewResults = interviewRepository.getInterviewResultByRoundIdAndScholarId();

for (LightRecruiterScholarResponse response : responses) {
    String val = null;

    for (InterviewDto dto : interviewResults) {
        if (dto.getId().equals(response.getScholarId())) {
            val = dto.getInterviewResult();
            break;
        }
    }

    response.setInterviewStatus(val);
}
```

Comment: get and find are database calls?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stream Filter of 1 list based on another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246998/stream-filter-of-1-list-based-on-another-list)

Answer (score 1):

This could be done straightforward:

```java
List<LightRecruiterScholarResponse> responses =
         eventScholarRepository.findScholarDetailsByEventId(eventId);
List<InterviewDto> interviewResults =
         interviewRepository.getInterviewResultByRoundIdAndScholarId();

responses.forEach(response -> response.setInterviewStatus(
                 interviewResults.stream()
                        .filter(dto -> dto.getId().equals(response.getScholarId()))
                        .map(InterviewDto::getInterviewResult)
                        .findFirst().orElse(null)));
```

This is not very efficient, because you iterate over `interviewResults` for every `response`. To fix it, you can build `Map` and use it:

```java
List<LightRecruiterScholarResponse> responses =
         eventScholarRepository.findScholarDetailsByEventId(eventId);
Map<String, String> interviewResults =
         interviewRepository.getInterviewResultByRoundIdAndScholarId().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(InterviewDto::getId,
                                              InterviewDto::getInterviewResult)); 
responses.forEach(response ->
   response.setInterviewStatus(interviewResults.get(response.getScholarId())));
```

Comment: @oleg.cherednik I tried the first approach but it seems to be giving NulPointerException.
Basically, I need to set the interviewResult field for the list named responses and return that list from the method.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik in my use case there might be a situation where there can be multiple null values being returned by the method getInterviewResult.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Map<String, String> map = interviewResults.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(InterviewDto::getId, InterviewDto::getInterviewResult));

responses.forEach(response ->
        response.setInterviewStatus(
                map.getOrDefault(response.getScholarId(), null)));
```

The idea is to create a Map of `Id` for key and `InterviewResult` for value, and then for each element in `responses` you set `InterviewStatus` which you can find it in the map by `ScholarId` which can replace `if (dto.getId().equals(response.getScholarId()))`